# How to reference different directories in dart files?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app which has many screens, and it will have many more in the future. The main.dart file is now getting very crowded and confusing, and I would like to separate some files so it is more legible. For example, I want all dart files that are about “option A” to be in a new directory/file called “option A”, and I want all the dart files about “option B” to be in a new file called “option B”, and so forth. My question is, how do I import the new directories, such as “option A” in another file? If it’s clearer this way, how can I use some properties and functions/classes from “option A” in an “option B” file? I am not quite sure how to do so, so any help would be appreciated.

As for what I tried, I tried to import the option A file into the option B file, so I could use some properties from option A. But the import function doesn’t let me import any other directory.

Comment: The keyword for importing another file is [`import`](https://dart.dev/language/libraries). Beyond that it’s not clear what you’re asking

Comment: Apologies, I am not great with English. What I need help with is that the import function doesn’t work for importing other directories, at least not for me, and that is what I need help with. It works fine with other files, but I get an error whenever I try to import new directories.

Comment: Dart only imports files, not directories. Maybe that’s the misunderstanding

Comment: `import 'subdirectory/some_file.dart';`.  Or `import 'package:package_name/path/to/file.dart';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you import another directory/file using this structure:

```
import 'Testing/testingstuff.dart';
```

Where the first word, "Testing/" is the name of the directory, and the word following after is the name of the file. In the example that I made here, "Testing/" is the name if the directory, and "testingstuff.dart" is the name of the file inside said directory. I hope this helps!